# Difference in pixel for same length of characters

Tags: html, css, user-interface

While working in css I had faced one issue.

The character with same number of length has difference in pixel values.

```
<html>
<div>
<p><b>WWWWW</b></p>
<p><b>IIIII</b></p>
<p><b>AAAAA</b></p>
</div>
</html>
```

**WWWWW**

**IIIII**

**AAAAA**

Both has same [5] character length.
How we can adjust them in CSS?

Comment: use a monospace font or an unstyled `<pre>`-tag

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am using this in circle in my webpage with padding-left. But it is not aligned properly when it comes with different data with same length

Comment: You might want to `text-align: center` it

Comment: font-family: monospace solved the issue

Comment: is there any other option without changing font? 
Even js changes will be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `font-family: monospace;`

This will use a font that reserves the same horizontal space for each letter, regardless of their actual width

```css
* {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p><b>WWWWW</b></p>
  <p><b>IIIII</b></p>
  <p><b>AAAAA</b></p>
</div>
```

In my example that font will be applied to *all* text, but you can of course restrict it to particular element/s by using a tag, class or ID selector (or any combined selector you come up with) instead of the `*` selector in the CSS rule I used.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in CSS, the maximum you can specify is `font-family: monospace`. [Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MGjQjQ) you have a JS solution.

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="scaled">WWWWWWWWWW</div>
<div class="scaled">IIIIIIIIII</div>
<div class="scaled">AAAAAAAAAA</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.scaled > span { 
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```js
$('.scaled').each(function(){
  let $scaled = $(this);
  let chars = $scaled.text().split('');
  let charsSpans = chars.map((char) => $('<span>' + char + '</span>'));

  $scaled
    .empty()
    .append(charsSpans);
});
```